# Wifi 5GHz AP Mode: What does `no IR` means and can I bypass it?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I bought a Intel 7260-ac wifi adapter (support 802.11ac) and want to setup it in AP mode (hotspot) in 802.11ac but it failed.

Then I noticed that `iw list` shows all 5GHz channels as `(no IR)` as below:

```
Frequencies:
* 5180 MHz [36] (16.0 dBm) (no IR)
* 5200 MHz [40] (16.0 dBm) (no IR)
* 5220 MHz [44] (16.0 dBm) (no IR)
* 5240 MHz [48] (16.0 dBm) (no IR)
* 5260 MHz [52] (16.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
DFS state: usable (for 1284 sec)
* 5280 MHz [56] (16.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
DFS state: usable (for 1284 sec)
* 5300 MHz [60] (16.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
DFS state: usable (for 1284 sec)
...
```

I googled about it and found this: http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-wireless/msg124066.html saying that **"The NO-IR flag then means you cannot use modes of operation that require you to initiate radiation first"**

Also, I found that it's related to **"world regulatory domain"** which restrict some usage in some wireless frequencies, and it's different in some country.

**So here's my question:** is the `no IR` restriction set by linux kernel or by hardware? If it's by linux kernel, can I just set it to another country which allows it? (Or a custom configuration if no country allows it?) How?

*PS: I'm not sure if it's the right place to ask this question but I don't see where else I can go.. Thanks in advance!*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you correctly noticed, this has to do with the regulatory domain. It is both, set by the hardware (pre-programmed for use in ...) and by the userland (iw / CRDA [Central Regulatory Domain Agent, a udev helper]). The thing is, you can only *lessen* the spectrum of available channels.

Lookup current RD: `iw reg get`
set RD: `iw reg set <CC>` with  being the [ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 2-character code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) for the country you want to set.

#### Explication

> Linux allows changing regulatory domains in compliance with regulatory restrictions world wide [...]. In order to achieve this devices always respect their programmed regulatory domain and a country code selection will only enhance regulatory restrictions. [...].

#### Example

> If your device was programmed for operation in the US (which allows operation on channels 1-11 on the 2.4 GHz band) and you visit Japan (which allows operation on channels 1-14) and you change your regulatory domain to JP you will not be able to use channel 12, 13 or 14 (CCK). But if you have a device programmed for operation in Japan and visit the US and you select US as your regulatory domain you will have channel 12-14 disabled.

http://wireless.kernel.org/en/developers/Regulatory/CRDA#Using_iw_to_change_regulatory_domains

Answer (score 1):

To bypass regulatory restrictions enforced by your hardware, and according you have good reasons to do that, you can patch your driver. I recently wrote [a post about that regarding Atheros chipsets](http://renaudcerrato.github.io/2016/05/30/build-your-homemade-router-part3/).

Comment: Any relevant information from that site should be included in the answer, as opposed to linking to it.

Comment: The whole procedure won't properly fit here.

Comment: @Jarmund so when the original info is fixed or updated, it would have to be edited at *two* locations instead of one, right?

Answer (score 1):

The regulatory domains are set by the kernel, you can use the [wireless-regdb](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/sforshee/wireless-regdb.git) and [crda](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/mcgrof/crda.git/) packages to edit the `regulatory.bin` & `regulatory.db` files and create the approriate `.pem` files

Before compiling wireless-regdb, you can edit the `db.txt` file and remove/edit the settings for every regulatory domain. This will allow you to do fun stuff like removing the `no IR` parameter and changing the max TX power of your desired country (or create a new country with custom settings).
This is very useful if you need inject packets on a channel that normally doesn't let you be the first to initiate radiation.

[Kali Screenshot: No IR removed & TX set to 33dBm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkO72.png)

**Tutorial for Kali/Debian:** https://miloserdov.org/?p=337

**BEWARE:** This is most likely illegal to do in your country and should only be done for research, development and/or educational purposes. Follow your local laws please.

I would also suggest that you get your amateur radio license before attempting this, it will give a better understanding of the laws and potential risks of changing these settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable DFS, if you are using hostapd, edit your hostapd.conf and set:

```
ieee80211h=0
```

restart the server and it will work.